# How to create a missing bold font in ConTeXt using overlays?

Tags: context, bold

I’m using ConTeXt and a font called “CMU Concrete”. I’d like to create a better bold font than the one provided (it’s not bold enough). Instead of using FontForge or fake bold, I tried to do it directly in ConTeXt by creating the `\pmb` command (Poor Man's Bold ;) ):

```
\defineeffect[outline][alternative=outer, rulethickness=0.3pt]
\define[1]\pmb{\startoverlay{\black#1}{\starteffect[outline]{\black#1}\stopeffect}\stopoverlay}
```

It works great for isolated words but not for sentences:

[image: comparison]

How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not a general solution, but you would probably have better luck if you applied `\pmb` word by word.  that's what's recommended for the `\pmb` in `amsmath` (and only as a last resort).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `both` alternative for the `effect` environment there is no need for the use of the `overlay` environment.

```
\defineeffect[heavy][alternative=both,rulethickness=.5pt]

\starttext

\input ward

\starteffect[heavy]
\input ward
\stopeffect

\stoptext
```

[image: Boldened text]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the overlay puts its contents in a box and then prints the box several times with a slight shift.  Obviously, you cannot have linebreaks there.

I suggest using the direct pdf approach and embolden the font there.  I prepared for you the macro `\pmb` which behaves like the usual `\bf`, but emboldens the font even more.  You can control the boldness with `\pmbweight`.

Inside of `\pmb` I switch to the normal bold font to make use of the adjusted kerning for the thicker glyphs.

```
\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][CMU Concrete]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]
\def\pmbweight{0.05}
\def\pmbon{\pdfliteral direct{2 Tr \pmbweight\space w}}
\def\pmboff{\pdfliteral direct{0 Tr}}
\def\pmb{\aftergroup\pmboff\pmbon\bf}
\starttext
Platon, dans le {\it Phèdre}, parle d'un «privilège de la beauté» par
rapport aux autres essences.

{\bf
  Platon, dans le {\it Phèdre}, parle d'un «privilège de la beauté»
  par rapport aux autres essences.
}

{\pmb
  Platon, dans le {\it Phèdre}, parle d'un «privilège de la beauté»
  par rapport aux autres essences.
}
\stoptext
```

> [image]